# Is "when" a conjunction in "I was going to call you when I got home."

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, conjunctions, parts-of-speech

Is the word "when" a conjunction in:

> I was going to call you when I got home.

If it's a conjunction I suppose "when" is usually reduced, what I mean by that is that the vowel in the word "when" is pronounced with a schwa sound. I said usually because I know stress can be shifted for special emphasis. Am I right?

Comment: I've edited the sentence you are asking about in the body of the question to match the title, because I figured it was a typo of a sort; if I was mistaken, please roll back to your previous version :-).

Answer (score 1):

Though dictionaries often label "when" as an adverb (So in Oald), the Oxford Guide to English Grammar by John Eastwood says:

We form an adverbial clause of time with a conjunction, eg

- Mozart could write music when he was only five. (Paragraph 250)

By the way, you can download this grammar. For more information on this grammar  [Link](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0194313514)

Answer (score 1):

> I was going to call you ***when*** I got home.

In the sentence according to the modern grammar **when** is a preposition. Except a few, modern grammar classifies as preposition all the words that tradition grammar calls subordinating conjunction or simply subordinator. They argue that like verb why a preposition can't take a declarative clause.

A verb as a head can take a NP as complement.

> He **hit** *him*. [The verb - **hit** - takes NP - *him* - as a complement]

But a verb as head can also take a declarative clause as complement, but then grammarians don't call them something else other than a verb.

> I **remember** *you promised to help*. [The verb - **remember** - takes a declarative clause - *you promised to help* - as a complement]

So if a verb is called a verb regardless whether it takes a NP or a declarative clause as complement, then why a preposition to be called a conjunction if it takes a declarative clause as complement. Hence modern grammarians decided to call it a preposition even if they take declarative clause (though they call *if, whether* etc subordinator).

> I was going to call you ***when*** I got home.

If we try to explain the POS of *when* from the point of view of traditional grammar, it's a conjunction, a subordinating conjunction that is. Because it connects two clause.

Comment: Neither conjunctions nor prepositions are defined by whether they take a declarative clause as a complement or not. They are defined by their function in the sentence: conjunctions link clauses and prepositions describe spatial or temporal relationships between phrases. They are completely different.

Comment: @RoaringFish So what are you going to call this *when*? And how to identify the function of *when* without taking into consideration what complement it takes?

Comment: The complement is immaterial. All you need is to be able to distinguish a phrase describing a location from a subordinating clause that doesn't. If you are going to maintain that *when* in the OP sentence is a preposition, you need to say how it **functions** as a preposition. It would also help if you gave specifics about all these 'modern grammarians' that you say now classify subordinating conjunctions as prepositions.

Comment: @RoaringFish Well, for that I first need to know if you consider these two to be different: ***when** take a a declarative clause as complement* and ***when** introduces a subordinate clause*?

Comment: No... you don't need my opinion on anything. You need to support your assertion with your explanation of how *when* is functioning as as a preposition. Your assertion; your explanation.

Comment: @RoaringFish See why I asked is because in your example you mentioned the same thing, but called it a conjunction. So I need to know a few things before answering your question.

Comment: Yes... I called it a conjunction because it introduces a clause. That is normal. That is what conjunctions do. If that is not the case and it is actually operating as a preposition, then stop asking me questions and explain to me **how** it is operating as a preposition!

Comment: @RoaringFish That is what I explained in my answer. And got a down-vote :P that and your comments clearly show you don't agree with my answer. Unless I know what causes you trouble how can I explain to you. If you still ask me to explain, will not I end up explaining the same way I did in my answer? Moreover in your first comment you said *conjunctions* introduces a clause, and according to your answer this *when* express temporal meaning. So a conjunction and a preposition both expresses a temporal meaning. Isn't it?

Comment: @RoaringFish **I called it a conjunction because it introduces a clause. That is normal. That is what conjunctions do.** => Well, in this sentence *I remember you promised to help.* **remember** also introduces a clause, is it also a conjunction?

Comment: Let me explain what prepositions do. They describe a **relationship** between two objects. In *the man is behind the desk* the preposition is describing how the postion of the man relates to the position of the desk, proven by *the desk is in front of the man* being available to describe the same situation with the relationship reversed. Similarly, *the flash came before the bang* describes the relationship between the flash and the bang. All I am asking of you is to show a similar relationship being described by *when* in the OP, but you are not doing it...

Comment: What clause do you think is being introduced by *remember* in *I remember you promised to help*?

Comment: @RoaringFish the clause being introduced by *remember* is *you promised to help*.

Comment: @RoaringFish *I came home before my son's arrival* - if I follow your explanation it establishes a relation between *"I"* and *"my son's arrival"*. The same relationship can be applied in this sentence - *I came home before my son arrived*. See in these cases your explanation can't bring a clear picture about preposition and conjunction. And you would be surprised to know there is no *conjunction* in modern grammar. Though there is *subordinator* and *coordinator*.

Comment: @RoaringFish *Children are advised to use this special pencil **when** drawing.*

Comment: *Remember* is not introducing a clause. What you have there is a reduced relative clause. The unreduced form is *I remember that you promised to help*. The relative clause is introduced by *that*, not by *remember* - which should be obvious as that would leave a semtence with no verb!

Comment: @RoaringFish that is totally wrong. It's never a relative clause. Even if you retain that *that*. *that* there is a subordinator, which is different from relativizer *that*.

Comment: Now... as you are clearly never going to give that explanation of how *when* is functioning as a preposition in the OP - or what a relative clause is let alone a reduced one - I see no point continuing this conversation.

Comment: @RoaringFish so the concept of *introduction* here is pretty murky. Isn't it?

Comment: @RoaringFish we will talk about relative clause later. Probably for a preposition you are looking for a noun after it? It's not always the case. I have already pointed out some problem with that concept. Nor is your explanation correct, as I have shown in the comments. Well, if you still think to be a preposition we have to have a noun after a presentation, I have shown a sentence in the comment where a noun phrase appears after *when*.

Comment: It is a free relative clause introduced by a relative pronoun and functioning as the object of the verb *remember* in the matrix clause *I rember [X]*. And how do you conclude that in *when drawing* the verb *drawing* is a noun phrase??

Comment: ... and still you refuse to explain how *when* functions as a preposition in *I was going to call you when I got home*, and instead talk about anything but that. Until you produce that explanation of the relationship it describes, I really have no interest in all these evasions you are throwing up - they are quite tiresome and utterly pointless.

Comment: @RoaringFish right, I'm not very comfortable calling *drawing* a noun. I would prefer to call it Gerund-participle form of verb. But since you follow the traditional grammar and in traditional grammar verb + ing is a gerund and a gerund is a noun, I used that terminology. But even if it's a verb  it's coming after preposition like *he will do it after going there* here *going* is a verb coming after the preposition - *after*.

Comment: @RoaringFish all *why* question is best answered with *because* but here it's not possible. It's not possible to explain it the way you want it to be. Because some of the concepts are murky. But still I will try. Take *before*, it's a preposition and a conjunction. In *he arrived before the arrival of his son* here the relationship is being made between his arrival and his son's arrival, right? But here in this example the same relation is being made - *he arrived before his son arrived.*. But in the last sentence you call it a *conjunction*. The same relation and meaning but different name.

Comment: So modern grammarians included it into preposition most of what traditional grammar calls conjunction.

Comment: Listen.. I am a highly educated professional linguist, and have been for years. Don't waffle at me about 'murky concepts', or about these 'modern grammarians' you keep referring to - they are my colleagues and they don't say what you claim, which is why you ignored my request for specifics of who they are. We are discussing the sentence *I was going to call you when I got home*. Not any other sentences you have invented. Just that one. You say that in that sentence - not any other - *when* is a preposition. Explain how it functions as a preposition **in that sentence** and without the waffle.

Comment: @RoaringFish i am not a linguist. Sorry. All I learned from the books your friends wrote :-) maybe my concepts are wrong. But you know better in this field. I was not arguing, was not in any intention of "waffling" at you. It's a public forum, I don't want to ask your friends' name nor your name. I know very few people in your field :(

Comment: I am not saying I am right because I am a linguist. I am saying I am a linguist so I will have no problems following your explanation of *when* being a preposition, and its murky concepts.

Comment: @RoaringFish that's fine :-) for more information about this topic, please refer to Cambridge Grammar of English Language page 615. It will be helpful.

Comment: I think you should read that again. It says what I said in my initial response to your answer - you cannot assign a word class on the basis of its complement. You have to look at the way the word functions, which is precisely why I keep asking you to explain how *when* is functioning as a preposition in the OP's example.

Comment: @RoaringFish Given that adverbs don't generally take content clauses as complements and that there are only five subordinators commonly recognised in grammars such as OMEG, CaGEL, ASIEG and so forth and that *when* ain't one of those five and that *when* is only recognised as a preposition in those grammars, I don't think MFI needs to justify very much here.

Comment: .... and here comes the prescriptive grammarian...  I don't really care what your grammar book says. I can find an equal number that contradict your grammar book by stating that *when* is never a preposition, which is precisely why your "my grammar book sez..." response to every issue is pointless. If you want to be convincing that *when* is a preposition in the OP sentence you have to show that it functions as a preposition, which MFI has failed to do. If it isn't doing what prepositions do, then it isn't a preposition - this isn't rocket science!

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a conjunction. Here 'when' is an adverb.

> I was going to call you when I got home.

Take for instance the below segment of the sentence:

> I was going to call you.

Okay when?

> When I got home.

An Adverb is a word that describes or adds more meaning to a verb. ***Call*** is the verb here and ***when*** is an *Adverb of Time*.

Comment: Thanks. In that case "when" is a content word and it's most likely pronounced with a clear /ɛ/ vowel sound. Am I right? May I ask one more question. Is the verb "was" a helping verb in the sentence above?

Comment: I'm not quite sure with what you are asking about the pronunciation. Although, about the was/am battle.

You could either go with 'I'm going to call you when I *get* home'

Comment: ====Please ignore previous comment====

I'm not quite sure with what you are asking about the pronunciation. Although, about the was/am battle.
You could either go with 'I'm going to call you when I *get* home' or 'I was going to call you when I *got* home'.
Note the change of tense with 'get and got'. The first sentence is a *simple future* sentence meaning you would call when you get home. But the second is a classic example of *Future in Past*. See http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/futureinpast.html for more help.

Comment: As far as I know, the only pronunciation *when*  has is /wen/. I don't see why it should change for this context. Refer [this](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/when_1?q=when)

Comment: I'm not sure about that. As a conjunction it's most likely reduced and pronounced with a schwa vowel as long as stress is not shifted for special emphasis. From dictionary.com /ʰwɛn, wɛn; unstressed ʰwən, wən/  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/when?s=t 
but if it's an adverb it most likely pronounced with the /ɛ/ vowel because content words are usually not reduced.

Comment: "when" is a conjunction in "when I got home". And "when" is always pronounced /wen/.

Comment: @rogermue The Longman Pronunciation Dictionary lists a reduced form with schwa.  This is unsurprising given that *when* is always a function word. In some accents you may also hear /wɪn/.

Answer (score -3):

It is a conjunction. Two things happen in the example sentence: first arrive home, and then call, refered to in two clauses and the *when* connects them.

However, it is a subordinating conjunction (sometimes called a "trigger word") introducing an adverbial clause, and on the principle that words introducing new information take a strong pronunciation the vowel is not reduced to a schwa.

*As, [**when**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/as-when-or-while) and while are conjunctions. In some uses as, when and while can mean the same, but they can also have slightly different meanings. We use them to introduce subordinate clauses.*(From Cambridge "*English Grammar Today*")

*A conjunction (also called a connective) is a word such as and, because, but, for, if, or, and **[when](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/conjunctions)**. Conjunctions are used to connect phrases, clauses, and sentences.* (From *Oxford Dictionary*)

*In English, there are lots of subordinating conjunctions, but the most common ones, along with a few examples of how subordinating conjunctions are used, are as follows:*

*[**when**](http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/conjunctions/subordinating-conjunctions.html) - “When I see you smile, I can face the world”*
(From *Your Dictionary*)

*As well as the coordinating conjunctions noted and explained above, there is a whole raft of subordinating conjunctions. Some of them are:
...
**[when](http://www.bristol.ac.uk/arts/exercises/grammar/grammar_tutorial/page_27.htm)**
....*
(From Bristol University *Improve Your Writing*)

*Subordinating conjunctions are used to join independent clauses to make complex sentences. The subordinating conjunctions are as follows: after, although, as, as if, because, before, even if, even though, if, if only, rather than, since, that, though, unless, until, **[when](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/engagement/2/1/37/)**, where, whereas, wherever, whether, which, and while.* (From *Purdue OWL*)